# Get Least Significant Bit in PHP from Hex

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

I have a file with hex code and I need to get all the least significant bits from every byte in the file, concatenate them, split them in groups of 8 and then convert the bytes into ASCII. My problem is to extract the LSB from every byte.

The hex file looks like this (but is much longer):

```
58 00 00 1F 58 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1C 22 23 1F 26 25 1E 2C 26 20 31 2B 22 38 2F 26 42 36 25 47 37 24 49 39 22
```

My code looks like this:

```
<?php
// Read file, remove spaces
$file = implode('', explode(' ', file_get_contents('vogel.hex')));

// Save LSB
$bits = array();
for ($i = 1; $i < strlen($file); ++$i)
{
    $bits[] = $file[$i] & 1;
}

// Split LSB array into chunks of 8 bits.
$bytes = array_chunk($bits, 8);

// Implode byte arrays, convert to decimal, convert to ASCII.
foreach ($bytes as $byte)
{
echo chr(bindec(implode('', $byte)));
}
?>
```

I think that the splitting and converting part should work correctly, but I think I made a mistake when extracting the LSB. Can someone provide an example how I can extract the LSB?

I slightly edited my code, so that I start reading the bits at position 1. Then the decimal representation is within the ASCII range and the script outputs an actual ASCII character.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply build up the bit string within the for loop, skipping the entire array procedure:

```
$bits = '';
for ($i = 1; $i < strlen($file); $i++) {
    $bits .= (($file[$i] & 1) == 0) ? '0' : '1';
    if ($i % 8 == 0) {
       echo bindec($bits);
       $bits = '';
    }
}
```

Of course, you'd have some dangling bits if the input file's size isn't a multiple of 8.

Comment: The code is for one time purpose only, therefore I didn't care about speed or good. But I have a question. Why do you start the loop with index 1 and does it matter if the spaces are still inside the $file string?

Comment: At the time I wrote my answer you had your loop starting at 0, and guess I got thrown off by the pre-increment (`++$i`) in the loop definition.

Answer (score 1):

what about shifting the hex left for hexvalue/2 times?

```
$hex = 0x05;
$shiftVal = (0 + $hex)/2;
echo $hex>>$shiftVal;//should output 1
```

another approach is to convert the hex to a number and see if it's odd or even:

```
$hex = 0xad;
echo $hex%2;
```

Comment: Do I need to apply this to every character? Thus if the input is `42 4D`, do I apply to `42` and `4D` or do I apply to to `4`, `2`, `4`and `D`?

Comment: a hex  number is represented by a group of 2 chars..so you should apply it to `42` and `4d` not to every char separately

Comment: Ok, thanks. I get the exactly same result as with my code. But it is still not what I expected/required. Maybe I made somewhere else a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of programmers might cringe at your solution, but it works just fine with both [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebcdic).  I don't know of any other character set one might possibly be using with PHP.

The least significant bit of the character digit is the same as the value it represents.  So your code will work.   But it really deserves to have a comment explaining it relies on the least significant bit of the ASCII/EBCDIC display codes being the same as the digit.